# Unable to authenticate Quickbook API

Tags: java, quickbooks

I am trying to authenticate against OAuth based Quickbook API through a java program which is following,

```
    OAuthAuthorizer authorizer = new OAuthAuthorizer(consumerKey,
            consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
    try {
        Context context = new Context(authorizer, apptoken,
                ServiceType.QBO, realmID);

        DataService service = new DataService(context);
        Customer customer = getCustomer();
        service.addAsync(customer, new CallbackHandler() {

            @Override
            public void execute(CallbackMessage message) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(message.getAttachableResponse());
            }
        });
    } catch (FMSException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have provided values for consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret token, app token and realmId but still I am getting an exception which is following,

```
      com.intuit.ipp.exception.FMSException: ERROR CODE:3200, ERROR   
      MESSAGE:message=Exception authenticating OAuth; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401, ERROR DETAIL:null
```

Am I  doing something wrong or missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're getting a "401 Unauthorized" response back. Usually, this indicates that you're either not sending your OAuth credentials, or they are not valid.

Are you sure our OAuth tokens are valid? Are you sure they haven't expired? Did you go through the 3-legged OAuth process to get your OAuth tokens?

Comment: i am getting "401 Unauthorized " error . when i am requesting 
"/v2/​{tenant_id}​/flavors/detail " in Compute API v2 extensions 
what is the problem ? and where i got OAuth tokens ?

Comment: You can refer to the Intuit developer instructions to get your OAuth tokens: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0050_your_first_request/0100_get_auth_tokens  That URL is probably incorrect as well -- what data are you trying to get?